# A namespace internal to the library

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, phpstorm

I'm working on a composer library that has one namespace containing classes that are used only by the rest of the library and should not be used by the users of the library.

Since the class names are similar to public classes, IDEs (in my case PhpStorm) often suggest using classes from that internal namespace with auto-complete, which can result in confusion.

Is it possible to hide that whole namespace from the users? If not, is there a convention that would prevent IDEs from showing those classes in auto-complete, or at least, not prioritize them?

Comment: Currently not after a pc that has some IntelliJ IDE installed, but you should be able to configure autocompletion like this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/auto-completing-code.html#configure-code-completion

Comment: Try adding `@internal` tag for PHPDoc comment for such class -- might help (in theory it should).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, I've tried that and PhpStorm will sort `@internal` classes last when showing the auto-complete popup.